# azure media service v3 upload from https url

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-media-services

does anyone know how we can upload to azure media service asset from a url without encoding? 
the video stored on s3 amazon is in mp4 format and I don't need to encode it (it takes time), but I need to upload it to my azure media service and make it public for streaming on client side video players.
I use asp.net and azure media service sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Media Services before, and indeed indexed at time of upload. However, this blog seems to cover your scenario
https://blog.genreof.com/post/azure-media-services–indexing-existing-videos

Comment: It is pasted wrong due to markup and im on a phone.  Use the complete url even after last dash

Comment: thx patrick , I'm using api v3 the blog was for legacy v2 api btw I'm not sure if indexing videos enables me to trim them later. did you trim or subclip your indexed videos via api?

Comment: Sorry, no I didn't trim or subclip